# Como obtener los datos de un ArrayList que fue creado en una clase, y quiero llamarlo de otra, cuando lo llamo los datos salen vacios

Tags: java, poo, objeto, class

Tengo varias clases, la clase principal donde esta el método main, una clase proveedor, una clase `listproveedor`, y quiero poder acceder al objeto creado desde la clase principal, lo cual puedo hacer correctamente, sin embargo, cuando quiero acceder a objeto desde la clase `ListProduct`, no genera ningún error, pero no carga los datos del objeto:

```java
package principal;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        MenuPrincipal();
    }
    
    public static void MenuPrincipal() {
        ListPerson obj =new ListPerson();
        ListProduct obj2= new ListProduct();
        ListProveedor obj3=new ListProveedor();
        
        byte opcion;
        do {
            opcion=Byte.parseByte(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            "Menu Principal\n"
            +"1. agregar empleado\n"
            +"2. Lista de empleados\n"
            +"3. Registrar Cliente\n"
            +"4. Lista de clientes\n"
            +"5. Registrar Producto\n"
            +"6. Lista de productos\n"
            +"7. Registrar Proveedor\n"
            +"8. Lista de proveedores\n"
            +"9. Facturar\n"
            +"10. ver Compras facturadas\n"
            +"11. Salir"        
            ));
            switch(opcion) {
                case 1:
                    obj.AddEmpleado();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    obj.GetEmpleado();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    obj.AddCliente();
                    break;
                case 4:  
                    obj.GetCliente();
                    break;
                    
                case 5:     
//                    obj3.SoloProveedor();//por que de aqui si
                    obj2.AddProducto();
                    break;
                    
                case 6:
                    obj2.GetProducto();
                    break;
                    
                case 7:
                    obj3.AddProveedor();
                    break;
                    
                case 8:
                    obj3.GetProveedor();
                    break;
                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Adios");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Encontrado");
                    break;
            }
        } while(opcion!=11);     
    }
}
```

De aquí puedo crear el objeto, agregar datos y obtenerlos, dependiendo de la opción que arroje el switch, hasta aquí todo bien.

```java
package principal;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ListProduct {  
    ArrayList<Producto> listproduc =new ArrayList();
    
    public String Input(String Text) {
       return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Text);
    }   
 
    public void AddProducto() {   
     String nombre=Input("Nombre");
     String marca=Input("Marca");
     String fechaven=Input("Fecha Vencimiento");
     String precio=Input("Precio");

     // el problema resulta aquí cuando intento acceder al objeto que cree en la otra clase
     ListProveedor obj3=new ListProveedor();
      String prueba =obj3.SoloProveedor();

     String provedor=Input (prueba+"Provedor");
    
     Producto producto= new Producto();
    
     producto.setNombre(nombre);
     producto.setMarca(marca);
     producto.setFechaVencimiento(fechaven);
     producto.setPrecio(precio);
     producto.setProvedor(provedor);
     
     listproduc.add(producto);
    }
     
    public void GetProducto() {
        String cadena="";
        for (int i = 0; i < listproduc.size(); i++) {
            cadena+="-----------------------------------------"+"\n";
            cadena+="Producto: "+(i+1)+"\n";
            cadena+="Nombre: "+listproduc.get(i).getNombre()+"\n";
            cadena+="Marca: "+listproduc.get(i).getMarca()+"\n";
            cadena+="FechaVencimiento: "+listproduc.get(i).getFechaVencimiento()+"\n";
            cadena+="Precio: "+listproduc.get(i).getPrecio()+"\n";
            cadena+="Proveedor: "+listproduc.get(i).getProvedor()+"\n";
            
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, cadena);
    }
}
```

Aquí voy a mostrar la clase `ListProveedor` para que la observen:

```java
package principal;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ListProveedor {
     ArrayList<Proveedor> listprove =new ArrayList();
    
    public String Input(String Text) {
       return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Text);
    }
    
     public void AddProveedor() {
     String nombre=Input("Nombre");
     String nit=Input("Nit");
  
     Proveedor proveedor= new Proveedor();
     
     proveedor.setNombre(nombre);
     proveedor.setNit(nit);
     
     listprove.add(proveedor);
    }
     
    public void GetProveedor() {
        String cadena="";
        for (int i = 0; i < listprove.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("mira como entro");
            cadena+="-----------------------------------------"+"\n";
            cadena+="Proveedor: "+(i+1)+"\n";
            cadena+="Nombre: "+listprove.get(i).getNombre()+"\n";
            cadena+="Nit: "+listprove.get(i).getNit()+"\n";    
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, cadena);
    }
     
    public String SoloProveedor() {
        System.out.println("llegue a la clase");
        String [] losValores=new String[listprove.size()];
        String cadena="";
        for (int i = 0; i < listprove.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("lllegue dentro de four");
            cadena+="Proveedor: "+(i+1)+"\n";
            cadena+="Nombre: "+listprove.get(i).getNombre()+"\n";
            losValores[i]=cadena;
            cadena="";
         System.out.println(losValores[i]+"prueba");
        }  
        Object seleccion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            null,
            "Seleccione opcion",
            "Selector de opciones",
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null,
            losValores,
            null);

         System.out.println("El usuario ha elegido "+seleccion);
        return (String) seleccion;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Introducción

En esta parte de tu código (Clase `ListProduct`):

```java
// el problema resulta aqui cuano intento acceder al objecto que cree en la otra clase
ListProveedor obj3=new ListProveedor();
String prueba =obj3.SoloProveedor();
```

Si mal no entendí, en la clase `ListProduct` estas intentado acceder al `obj3` que creaste en la otra clase (siendo la otra clase `Principal`).

El problema que tienes es que en realidad no estas accediendo al objeto `obj3` creado en la clase `Principal`. Si no que estas creando una nueva instancia de tipo `ListProveedor` en tu clase `ListProduct`.

Justamente en la linea `ListProveedor obj3= new ListProveedor();` estas creando una nueva instancia de la clase `ListProveedor` y la estas asignando a una variable llamada `obj3`.

> quiero poder acceder al objecto creado desde la clase principal, lo cual puedo hacer correctamente, sin embargo cuando quiero acceder a objecto desde la clase ListProduct, no genera ningún error, pero no carga los datos del objecto.

### Problema

El problema es que en `ListProduct` no estás usando la instancia de `obj3` creada en la clase `Principal`, si no que estas creando una nueva instancia que tiene `ArrayList<Proveedor> listprove =new ArrayList();`. Es decir, tiene el ArrayList vacío.

### Solución

Para poder utilizar la instancia creada en `Principal` dentro de `ListProduct` puedes enviar dicha instancia como parámetro de la función `AddProducto()`.

Esto sería:

En la clase `ListProduct`

```java
public void AddProducto(ListProveedor instanciaProveedor) { // Agrego el parametro de tipo 'ListProveedor'   
     String nombre=Input("Nombre");
     String marca=Input("Marca");
     String fechaven=Input("Fecha Vencimiento");
     String precio=Input("Precio");

     // ListProveedor obj3 = new ListProveedor(); <-- Esta línea no va
     String prueba = instanciaProveedor.SoloProveedor(); // <- instanciaProveedor es la instancia creada en la clase 'Principal'

     String provedor=Input (prueba+"Provedor");
    
     Producto producto= new Producto();
    
     producto.setNombre(nombre);
     producto.setMarca(marca);
     producto.setFechaVencimiento(fechaven);
     producto.setPrecio(precio);
     producto.setProvedor(provedor);
     
     listproduc.add(producto);
}
```

Y para llamar al método con el nuevo parámetro sería:

En la clase `Principal`

```java
case 5:
   obj2.AddProducto(obj3);
   break;
```

---

EDIT:

Recomendaciones:

Te recomiendo que utilices nombres descriptivos para las instancias de tus objetos, así es más fácil leer tu código. Por ejemplo:

En vez de:

```java
ListPerson obj =new ListPerson();
ListProduct obj2= new ListProduct();
ListProveedor obj3=new ListProveedor();
```

Intenta con:

```java
ListPerson listPerson = new ListPerson();
ListProduct listProduct = new ListProduct();
ListProveedor listProveedor = new ListProveedor();
```

Esto es solo un consejo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue de mucha utilidad

Comment: Me alegro! Si te sirvió la respuesta y solucionó tu problema, considera marcar mi respuesta como "Aceptada".